# Fast array search by wildchar string?

Tags: javascript

I have an array in JavaScript, with indexes like `net.up, net.down, net, err, err.warn`

I have a string and I need to find all the indexes that match the string. Matching has a few special rules, though...

'net.*' would return `net.up, net.down`
'err' would just return `err`

It's very strict, ie, 'net.u*' would not return anything.

Currently, I'm thinking about splitting the string by the periods and comparing each segment against each segment, but this seems naive.

As per request, my code that works, but I feel is too naive and hope to improve:

```
o = {"hey":0,"hey.a":1,"hey.b":1,"no":0};
srch = "hey.*".split(".");
for(i in o) {
  match = true;
  parts = i.split(".");
  for(j=0;j<srch.length;j++) {
    if (parts[j]=="*" || srch[j]=="*") continue;
    if (parts[j] != srch[j]) {
      match=false;
      break; } }
  if (match)
    document.write("match: "+i+"<br>"); }
```

Comment: Array indexes are numeric. Do you have an object instead? Or do you want to search for *values* of the array?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I meant I have an object... JavaScript's objects always throw me off.

Comment: If you want to search in an array (what do you mean on "indexes"?), why don't you create a regex from your "query"?

Comment: Show what you've tried and what's not working. That will make your question much easier to understand. Right it looks like you're looking for suggestions, which is not what SO is for... but if you show what you've tried, then it makes it a great SO question

Comment: So what is the result, an array with just the keys or an object with key:value pairs? In any case, what you're looking for is regular expressions, it's like wildcards on steroids.

Comment: why should `net.u*` not return `net.up`? Can `*` only be replaced by full words?

Comment: Juan, I added my working code. Also, I'm looking to call a function using the value from each matching parameter, either by looping through all the parameters and looking for a match, or somehow getting a list of just the matching strings and looping through those.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think splitting the string by periods is naive. To determine a match, you need to verify that every part of an input string matches every part of a pattern. That seems like exactly what you want to do.

One possible way you could optimize this—if performance were super critical for some reason—might be to avoid allocating the arrays with `split` and instead walk each string bit by bit with `indexOf` (to find the next dot) and `substring`. But that code would be much more complicated and probably barely any faster, if at all.

Comment: Performance is very critical. It's a large project, for which this function is the absolute backbone. Every single action in the project will be calling this function so I need it to be the most efficient possible.

Comment: If your code is running on the server side, and the performance is critical but you have enough RAM, you could try to implement a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It's fast, but you have to construct it beforehand, but after you do this first step, it will be faster than usual linear search.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your edit this is what I would suggest, with the help of regular expressions you can make any pattern you'd like, no need to create your own wildcard system; regex is the ultimate wildcard:

```
var obj = {"hey":0,"hey.a":1,"hey.b":1,"no":0};

var hey = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key){
  return /^hey\.?.*?$/.test(key);
});

console.log(hey); //=> ["hey", "hey.a", "hey.b"]
```

**Edit:** If you just want a wildcard you can still use regex, something like this:

```
function filterwild(obj, wild) {
  wild = new RegExp('^'+ wild.replace(/\.(.+?)\*/,'\\.$1.*?') +'$');
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(k){ return wild.test(k) });
}

console.log(filterwild(obj,'hey')); //=> ["hey"]
console.log(filterwild(obj,'hey.*')); //=> ["hey","hey.a","hey.b"]
console.log(filterwild(obj,'hey.a*')); //=> ["hey.a"]
```

`wild` gives you a regex like `/^hey\.a.*?$/` (last example). Not sure this is the exact output you need; you can adjust the regular expression to your needs.

Here's a quick demo of the above: http://jsbin.com/ahixeq/2/edit

Comment: I think the wildcard system of using "*" to represent anything is actually very simple, and also pretty widely understood. I would actually *prefer* it to supporting any arbitrary regular expression, unless the OP has some reason for the latter. (For example, if the search string will be supplied via user input, allowing "*" as the only wildcard is much easier and safer than properly escaping and validating against potentially malicious regular expressions!)

Comment: @DanTao: I sort of agree. I would just map those characters to predefined regular expressions created on the fly on the `RegExp` constructor in that case.

Comment: Dan is correct. I only want to use * as the wildchar, and only for full words. sys.term.* should match sys.term.hello, but not sys.boot.done

Comment: So string replace the * for . and make a reg exp.

Comment: What about all of the other regexp symbols? Can you give some example code?

Comment: Check my edit, see if that works. As for the regex, I learned here http://www.regular-expressions.info/ like many other people I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question and the comments correctly, then perhaps you are looking for something like this.

javascript

```
var o = {
    "hey": 0,
    "hey.a": 1,
    "hey.b": 1,
    "no": 0
};

function filterWild(object, search) {
    var length = search.length,
        matches = [],
        searchLength = Infinity,
        length;

    if (length > 2 && search.slice(-2) === ".*") {
        search = search.split(".");
        length = search.length ;

        if (length > 2) {
            search = search.slice(-1).join(".") + ".";
            searchLength = search.length;
        } else if (length === 2) {
            search = search[0] + ".";
            searchLength = search.length;
        } else {
            search = search[0];
        }
    }

    for (i in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(i) && i.slice(0, searchLength) === search) {
            matches.push(i);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

console.log(filterWild(o, "hey"));
console.log(filterWild(o, "hey.*"));
console.log(filterWild(o, "hey.a*"));
```

output

```
["hey"]
["hey.a", "hey.b"]
[]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4xqKd/)

Here is a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-function-wildcard-filter) of the above function vs the regex version

A possible performance improvement is to use `switch` instead of the `if..else` statements, there may be others.

It's not using any ECMA5 code but does require ECMA3 compatibility, so it should be fairly browser friendly.